# What is the best lead when calling next on a declined bower?

Tags: euchre

Let's say that we have a scenario where the dealer has declined a ♠J.

You are sitting to the dealer's left, with ♥A, ♣K, ♣9, ♢Q, ♢10.

The advice I read at [this site](http://www.vegaseuchre.com/strategy.html) says that calling clubs is a reasonable call as it is likely the dealer was strong in red.  My own experience and skill level agrees with this.

The article also notes that a poor lead would be ♥A, as any spare club could pick up the trick (again agreed).

What seems to be the best lead from this position?

My thought would be to lead ♢10 and give my partner a chance to jump, but is there a better general strategy?  Leading ♢Q improves the odds of picking up the first trick myself, but to my mind, only marginally.

My general line of thought is that since I am void in spades, I'm best to become void in diamonds to increase my chances of using my trump on off suit leads by my opponents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a Eucre expert by any means, but in my opinion, **not leading the ♡A is foolish advice.**

If that's the only heart in your hand, then the odds are greater that your opponents will also have hearts. As you say, the dealer is likely strong in red. The best chance you have of winning the trick is on the opening lead. Why would you lead a suit which relies on your partner having an ace or being void in diamonds?

The worst case scenario: they will have to trump your ace, and since you only have two trump, neither top, and one bower is turned down, it is good to force your opponents to use their trump in that situation rather than, say, using their trump to overtrump yours.

Secondly, and more importantly, after you lead the Ace you will be void in hearts, and able to trump any further heart tricks. You're already void in Spades and can trump any of those tricks your partner can't take. You can slough off your diamonds on spades or hearts if your partner takes those tricks.

> My general line of thought is that since I am void in spades, I'm best to become void in diamonds to increase my chances of using my trump on off suit leads by my opponents.

Why lead a suit that you have two cards in when you can void hearts immediately?

Comment: While the dealer is likely strong in red and probably has a heart to follow a lead of ♡A, it's completely unknown what their partner has.  The off ace becomes valuable once everyone is void in trump, here we know where 3 are, 4 to find.  If the partner trumps my diamond, it gives my partner a chance to trump the trick with the dealer likely having to follow diamond.

Comment: IOW, leading ♡A opens my parter to trumping the trick.  Leading either diamond does the same thing, but leaves me with an off ace in reserve.

Comment: I don't understand this logic. Why do you need to keep it in reserve? A trick's a trick. You don't have any other high cards to play, so you don't need the lead later. Your best odds of taking the trick with ♡A are by leading it. If you lead diamonds, you only give your opponents a chance to slough hearts on them to trump your ace later.

Comment: I believe the logic is ♡A is vulnerable to 4 trump cards.  Were these out of play then leading ♡A is a guaranteed trick.  Then the hope is that on a diamond lead you draw a trump from the dealer's partner and one from your own partner reducing the total available to play to 2.  In this case your partner should now have the lead.  You then give them an opportunity to lead one of their strong suits, perhaps gaining a trick.  If your partner leads an off suit ace and is trumped then there is 1 trump remaining outstanding.  If your partner leads trump then you are holding the only remaining trump.

Comment: Then you can play the trump followed by the Ace to make your point.  There's an awful lot of conditions in there, and you are always at the mercy of the cards, but I think that is how the logic works.  I'm certainly interested in any other points of view on this though.

Comment: I agree with this lead. Clubs are too risky; you have no winners and worst case is that opponent on your left has J-A, sucking up your 9 and one of partner's on the same trick, leading to another club trick and then a spade or diamond for euchre. Diamonds are risky as well, knowing that you're almost certainly not winning that yourself. If your ace is trumped, it's likely with a card you wouldn't have taken anyway.

Comment: @Stephen OK, I understand the sequence and logic, but don't agree with the risk/odds calculation. It's more likely your Ace will take a trick than your partner will take diamonds. Also, you mention that if your partner leads an off suit ace later and is trumped that's another trump out of play. Well, it's the same result if someone trumps your Ace, so… you may as well lead it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my.

I finally digested the site you referenced.  It reminded me that creating a website doesn't require a degree or certification.

There is an awful lot of discussion on this particular thread which takes for granted this site offered sound advice.

It absolutely does not.  In fact, there are six pages' worth of advice which will quickly make you a mediocre player.

For the situation referenced, I can not think of a hand where I would call trump of the opposite bower.  I would not call anything whatsoever.

One quick aside about advice from that site which was touched on here: I have always played by the rule that, unless you have one card of a particular suit, you may not call that as trump.  Violating this is considered a form of cheating, which incurs terms agreed upon by house rules.

Answer (score 1):

Dusting off this old topic, I will preface this by saying that I am an extremely aggressive player.  Specific decisions with how risky of calls to make can depend heavily on how well I know my opponents and my partner.  The more aggressively my opponents play and the more defensively my partner plays, the more emboldened I am to make risky plays.

I would personally in this situation call clubs and **would lead with the 9 of clubs**.

My reasoning is that it very unlikely that the dealer has the other Jack, and almost as unlikely that the person to your left has the other Jack.  Your partner is the most likely player to have the other Jack (*though he might not have it either*).

Further, it is less likely that the dealer has strong aces (*else, he may have picked up the jack of spades with as little as one other spade and one ace kicker*).  Turning down a jack of spades is a very difficult thing to do for a dealer.

Finally, in leading clubs rather than diamonds or hearts, you reduce the chance that your opponents can cross trump you making your or your partner's ace(s) bad.

Note that in making this play, you are all but guaranteeing that you will personally take at most two tricks (once with your ace, and again with your king) and are relying on your partner to pick up the slack, but more often than not your partner will be good for the first trick (either with an ace or with the jack) and can then lead one of their own aces.  Also, remember that given an even distribution of card value, you should expect everyone to be capable of taking 1 trick, so relying on your partner for a trick is not as much of a stretch as one might think.

Have I made this play in the past and been set?  Yes, absolutely.  Have I made this play in the past and my partner takes all five tricks with me taking none?  Yes as well.  In my personal experience, it feels like I get the point at least 70% of the time with this call and lead, making it an overall positive expected return.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would only call clubs there if you need the point.  If you are in the lead or close then you are taking a risk.  The JAQ10 are out there and could be in your opponents hand. That is a good club hand but if you have no other spades its tough to call op a bower when you have a loner hand in the off suit.

Second when you do call clubs you need some help.  Quite a bit of help actually.  You lead ace is really the only point you can count.  Being short spades is good and should lead to another but that is not for sure. If you lead diamonds you will lose the lead and you can not be certian that hearts will be lead back.  And by the time it does one of your opponents may have had a chance to throw off their lone heart meaning they can trump your ace.

If an opponent has JA of clubs and you lose the first trick to an ace you are certian of going set.  Your partner may be able to throw off a card that is doing him no good with your ace.  That may short suit him in diamonds letting you lead diamonds back and he gets a point you desperately need.

Comment: But if dealer has a loner in clubs, then you're better off calling it yourself and giving them two as opposed to the four they'd otherwise get. I agree about the ace of diamonds being a huge problem, though.

Comment: @Dave - That is never getting back to the dealer. No one calling up the spade and the dealer having most of the clubs. You could be causing your partner to lose his loner. You may be able to keep the loner to 1 but you cost 2 if you go set.  If you need the point (you are down and your opponent could go out) then its a good call.  Ill take my chances otherwise and give my partner a chance to make a good call.

Comment: Well, you don't have a hand to call it. If the opponent to your left has a reasonably strong hand in diamonds or hearts, they might pass and put your partner in the same situation: call something and probably get set or call nothing and probably give up 4. If I were dealing, then no, I wouldn't expect it to go around, but if your partner doesn't have strength, then it's purely a defensive call as in the OP's situation.

Comment: @Dave If the dealer had a loner in clubs, then they would have likely been fine with making spades.  They'd have to have at least ♣J ♣A and would have picked ♠J.  At WORST the dealer would only have to deal with 1 outstanding club (only if the other 3 were all in another opponent's hand).  This whole question is precipitated on the idea that if the dealer turns down spades, they are probably strong in red suits.

Comment: @Dave I agree that it is a defensive call.  And I prefer to be an offensive player.  I prefer to give my partner an opportunity to call a stronger hand.  Granted if i can obviously see the guy next to me chomping at the bit for my pass I would make the call too.

Comment: @stephen That is true of the dealer but not of his partner. As I said if the dealer has a loner in clubs someone else has a suit to call trump in.  And in this case it is not you.

Comment: @Chad A lot of the point of this question is a "what if", since it's always easy to make a point on strong cards but playing from a weak position requires a different touch.  I also prefer to play offence but can certainly see where a defensive tact might be more beneficial.

Comment: @Stephen, what I meant to convey is that I think it is worthwhile to call clubs in the first place (addressing Chad's first point). If there is opposing strength in clubs, there's a little risk in calling it yourself, but not as much as if opponents have (as the article suggests) strength in another suit and you do not call anything.

Comment: @Dave - But there is little to gain, unless you are desperate.  And if you call it, up not leading the ace should be a capitol offense.